# Получение закрытой экспоненты в RSA

Tags: криптография, шифрование, rsa, криптоаналитика

Читаю про алгоритм RSA в википедии и не понимаю, как так получается, что секретная эспонента **d** вычисляется с помощью общедоступных данных (открытой экспоненты **e** и числа **n**). Ведь получение секретного ключа с помощью открытого ключа нарушает одно из основных требований к криптосистемам. Как так получается, что RSA сложно взломать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы вычислить `d` из `e`, нужно знать число `(p-1)(q-1)`, где `p` и `q` делители числа `N`.

Стойкость RSA основывается на сложности разложения больших чисел на множители. Несмотря на то, что все знают число `N` из открытого ключа, вычислительных мощностей в обозримом будущем в принципе не хватит для разложения `N` современных ключей на произведение `p` и `q`.

Например, число `1807082088687404805951656164405905566278102516769401349170127021450056662540244048387341127590812303371781887966563182013214880557` из первой статьи про RSA, опубликованной в 1977 году, раскладывали 17 лет (правда, авторы ожидали, что разложение потребует миллионы лет :) )

На текущий момент самый лучший результат по разложению чисел на множители - [число с 250 цифрами](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers#RSA-250), которое потребовало 2700 лет счёта на суперкомпьютере. Принимая во внимание, что в реальной жизни используются ключи в 2.5 раз длиннее, можно не переживать за стойкость RSA до массового внедрения квантовых компьютеров.

Comment: Но ведь значение (p-1)*(q-1) - это функция эйлера от числа n, которое можно быстро получить используя любой онлайн калькулятор функции эйлера (для таких значений, как в википедии), а кроме вычисления функции эйлера числа p и q нигде больше не используются. Поправьте пожалуйста, если я где-то ошибаюсь.

Comment: @Alyks функция Эйлера быстро считается только для 64-х битных чисел. Уже для 128 бит это будет далеко не так быстро. А для 2048 бит, рекомендуемых для практических применений, это невозможно трудоёмкая задача.